# How can I scaffold DbContext with all models for tables in the database on Runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working as a platform developer building a dynamic support for `EntityFrameworkCore`.

What I am actually trying to do is to seal EntityFramework from the exact project, with building a database models on runtime, storing them as an assembly dll file (instead of the project developer manually using command line tools to scaffold), enumerating the model assembly and registering them to `EntityFrameworkCore`, and exposing an IQueryable to the project builder so that they can query with linq expressions.

I tried using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding` but faild because all of those classes are constructed with interface arguments and there is no way to find implementions.

Is there a way to generate the model classes on runtime or some other solutions for dynamic accessing database with linq and `dynamic` typed models?

Comment: I don't know if you can do that, but when your table has a column removed, and your dynamic class is missing it, but your calling class requires it, you will of course get an error.

Comment: well I know that use weakly typed model is not a good way of using an O/R mapping framework but still I need the critical features like automatic sql generating, connection pool management and possibly any further problems that I have not concerned

Comment: As I have concerned, modification of database structure means there must be some BL layer upgrade and there must be a new build version, and when upgrading the server, the old model assembly is certainly required to be removed so that the program could regenerate it @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: But part of your BL change would require a regeneration of the database layer in the middle anyway. Unless I misunderstand the problem. You probably can generate the layer automatically using various VS build tools but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Have you checked CatFactory? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1160615/Scaffolding-Entity-Framework-Core-with-CatFactory

Comment: well, i dont think it a problem because anytime when I need to regenerate the database layer i just delete the generated dll file and when I the BL change does not require the database layer update, just keep the old one and thats fine. I can surely decide when the models would be updated, so I dont think it any harder than manually updating the ef scaffoldings @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: ah it seems the one im actually needing! ill check it out, thanks!@H.Herzl

Comment: It seems to be very nice but, CatFactory supports only MS SQL Server. I need to keep the compatibility to many database providers (at least MSSQL, MYSQL, Oracle) so i cannot use it.@H.Herzl

Comment: It's a shame because at this moment CF only support sql server... but wait you can create the structure for tables without import from existing sql server database

Comment: what I want to do is to create a rapid development framework for actual projects, I want to seal the whole DA layer from the project develper so that what they only need to do is to access the existing database with linq expression, without any modeling (I built a dynamic expression wrapper for linq so that they dont need any table structure). @H.Herzl

Comment: You can do that but a lot of that code is public internal hence can be broken in future releases.